# Сдвиг элементов матрицы по строкам и столбцам на Python

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм

В квадратной матрице (список списков) размером N x N нужно реализовать смещение элементов по строкам и столбцам: в начало строки/столбца добавляется новый элемент, а последний элемент строки/столбца вытесняется.

Пример матрицы:

```
[[1 2 3 4],
 [1 2 3 4],
 [1 2 3 4],
 [1 2 3 4]]
```

Пример с добавлением нового элемента в начало второй строки:

```
[[1 2 3 4],
 [0 1 2 3],
 [1 2 3 4],
 [1 2 3 4]]
```

Пример с добавлением нового элемента в начало второго столбца:

```
[[1 0 3 4],
 [0 2 2 3],
 [1 1 3 4],
 [1 2 3 4]]
```

Смещение в строке можно сделать так:

```
matrix[i].insert(0, value)
matrix[i].pop()
```

Или через deque:

```
row = deque(matrix[i], len(matrix))
row.appendleft(value)
matrix[i] = list(row)
```

Пробовал сделать то же со столбцом:

```
col = deque(list(zip(*matrix))[i], len(matrix))
```

Но как впихнуть col обратно в матрицу?

Также можно повернуть матрицу (превратить столбцы в строки), сделать смещение в строке и повернуть матрицу обратно.
Посоветуйте оптимальное решение. Спасибо!

*Обновлено*

Сделал так:

```
def shift_col(col, x):
    n = len(matrix)
    row = deque(list(zip(*matrix))[col], n)
    row.appendleft(x)
    for i in range(n):
        matrix[i][col] = list(row)[i]
```

Comment: можно повернуть, если не хотите цикл написать

Comment: а использование модуля numpy не будет оптимальным решением?

Comment: @strawdog если домашнее задание, или объемы примерно как в вопросе, то в numpy мало смысла

Comment: @splash58 Не домашнее задание, но numpy - слишком круто.

Comment: @mad_cat не вижу, что тут особенно крутого - использовать numpy.roll() в нужной оси, затем записать новый элемент на нужное место.

Comment: @strawdog, я недавно начал учить Python и, наверное, правильнее будет обойтись без numpy.